# I'm not getting the specific value by id in jquery from the table row, it shows 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to catch the value from the table row when clicking on the add to cart btn. The table is here.

```html
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
       <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Availability</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Vendor</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

    <% for(var i=0; i < medicines.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row"><span id="id"><%= medicines[i].id %></span></th>
         <td><%= medicines[i].name %></td>
         <td><%= medicines[i].availability %></td>
         <td><%= medicines[i].price %></td>
         <td><%= medicines[i].category %></td>
         <td><%= medicines[i].type %></td>
       <td><%= medicines[i].vendor %></td>
         <td>
            <input type="number" id="availability" name="quantity" min="1" max="<%= medicines[i].availability %>" required>
                                               
            <input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Add to Cart">
         </td>
     </tr>
    <% } %>
                              
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and Jquery code is...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
            
    $("#myTable").on('click', '#btn', () => {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");

        var col = row.find("#id").html();
        alert(col);
    });
            
});
</script>
```

I should get the value of the specific column of the row I click. But in the alert it shows undefined!

**How can I get the value of id="id" from the row I click of the table?**

> Update:  When I used function() {} inside the click event instead () => {}    arrow function it worked!

Comment: it's not technically allowable to have multiple elements with the same ID in the DOM, which you will have. That's usually not a problem in practice but maybe you've found a case where it is. Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: @Saqib, has any of the solutions worked for you?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Yes, I used arrow function which didn't work. Instead, used normal function() {}, it worked magically.

Comment: @Saqib, [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions/) might be helpful for you to understand the difference between regular functions and arrow functions better. By the way, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) which one is best in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use jquery code after table definition.
You could get id of row which contains button you click by adding your onclick function inside table.
As long as you make your table by using loop, you know id inside your template.
Please try add `<%= medicines[i].id %>` inside your `onclick=""` inside your html.
Sorry, I am not expert at <% code so don't know how to insert <% code inside html.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Just add a click event on your `td`'s button.
2. Find the closest row of the clicked button by `$(this).closest("tr");`.
3. Find the specific cell from the row by using `$row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();`, here first child is the id so `td:nth-child(1)`.

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
    var $text = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text(); // Find the text
    alert($text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Availability</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Vendor</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Napa</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Paracitamol</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Add to Cart"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**`Update:`**
Since you have multiple rows, you can use the button click event by setting `class` rather than the `id` in this way:

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var $text = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text(); // Find the text
    alert($text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Availability</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Vendor</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Napa</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Paracitamol</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Add to Cart"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Napa</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Paracitamol</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Add to Cart"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *data-attribute*, use a class for button as the selector

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-submit" value="Add to Cart" data-id='<%= medicines[i].id %>' >
```

and in the event listener get it as follow:

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function () {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
```

or find the clicked row and get `id`

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find(":first").text();
            console.log(id);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the code to this code below, it worked fine. Which I realized, the arrow function didn't work for me!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
        
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");

        var col = row.find("#id").text();
        alert(col);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: A reminder on this one as well.  Since you self-answered, please do Accept your answer (or someone else's).  This helps close out the question so that Community Bot doesn't bump it looking for new answers.  Thanks!